# Umbraco MVC: Repeating same pattern content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco Mvc. A page consists of repeating content -heading and body text. User can be able to add or remove any number of such type of content panel.

How can i implement this?

For this page i added a document type, template and content. I am not sure what to do next?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: For faster and better answers you should post your question to http://our.umbraco.org/

Comment: Yeah, i tried there just before. waiting for answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I thought I'd leave a note here.

## Umbraco 7

Both [Nested Content](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/nested-content) and [Archetype](http://imulus.github.io/Archetype/) are both great packages for creating repeating content on a page/node in Umbraco. Nested Content is actually so good, **as of version 7.7.0, it is included in Umbraco**!

Another way to create repeating content is to create the content as nodes/pages in Umbraco, then picking it (using a multinode picker) node/page where you want the data to show.

## Umbraco 6

Checkout [uComponents](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/ucomponents) as it allows for repeating content too.

**Self promotion**

My old blog post [The best Umbraco packages of 2017](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/best-umbraco-packages-2017) contains a little more information about these specific packages.